# AS3 DoubleClick question

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mouse, double-click

Has anyone got movieclip with nested clips to have a doubleclick = true; property working. The only way I could get it to work was by setting mouseChildren to false which I need to be true!! Any leads/ideas would be welcomed!

J

Comment: Can you outline why you need your child content to be mouse enabled? Maybe there's a way to achieve the same while keeping mouseChildren false, allowing your doubleclick to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `doubleClickEnabled` to true, if you haven't already done so.

Answer (score 0):

You could try filtering the click event by checking the target name. I guess you need the clicks for different functions so in each function you can decide to what target ( movie clip ) you want the function to react.

```
function clickHandler (event:MouseEvent ):void
{
  if( event.target.name == theMovieClipINeed.name )
     fire();
}
```